# UnicodeEncodeError on joining file name

Tags: python, unicode, filenames

It throws out "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)" when executing following code:

```
filename = 'Spywaj.ttf'
print repr(filename)
>> 'Sp\xc2\x88ywaj.ttf'
filepath = os.path.join('/dirname', filename)
```

But the file is valid and existed on disk. Filename was extracted from "unzip -l" command. How can join filenames like this?

**OS and filesystem**

```
Filesystem: ext3    relatime,errors=remount-ro 0       0
Locale: en_US.UTF-8
```

**Alex's suggestion** os.path.join works now but I still cannot access the file on disk with the filename it joined.

```
filename = filename.decode('utf-8')
filepath = os.path.join('/dirname', filename)
print filepath
>> /dirname/u'Sp\xc2\x88ywaj.ttf'
print os.path.isfile(filepath)
>> False

new_filepath = filepath.encode('Latin-1').encode('utf-8')
print new_filepath
>> /dirname/u'Sp\xc2\x88ywaj.ttf'
print type(filepath)
>> <type 'unicode'>
print os.path.isfile(new_filepath)
>> False

valid_filepath = glob.glob('/dirname/*.ttf')[0]
print valid_filepath
>> /dirname/Spywaj.ttf (SO cannot display the chars in filename)
print type(valid_filepath)
>> <type 'str'>
print os.path.isfile(valid_filepath)
>> True
```

Comment: Are you sure it's '/dirname' and not u'/dirname'?

Comment: @Ignacio, same problem with u'/dirname'.

Comment: Yes, the problem would be expected with u'/dirname'. Your question as is shows no issue, so somewhere in there you have a non-ASCII character. We need to see it in order to verify though.

Comment: @Ignacio, what did you mean? I tried '/dirname' and u'/dirname' but none of them worked. I just wonder how to join valid filepath in program in order not to lose access to the extracted files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In both Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) and Windows-1252, 0xc2 would a capital A with a circumflex accent... doesn't seem to be anywhere in the code you show!  Can you please add a

```
print repr(filename)
```

before the `os.path.join` call (and also put the `'/dirname'` in a variable and print its repr for completeness?).  I'm thinking that maybe that stray character **is** there but you're not seeing it for some reason -- the `repr` will reveal it.

If you do have a Latin-1 (or Win-1252) non-Ascii character in your filename, you have to use Unicode -- and/or, depending on your OS and filesystem, some specific encoding thereof.

**Edit**: the OP confirms, thanks to `repr`, that there are actually *two* bytes that can't possibly be ASCII -- 0xc2 then 0x88, corresponding to what the OP thinks is one lowercase L.
Well, that sequence would be a Unicode uppercase A with caret (codepoint 0x88) in the justly popular **UTF-8** encoding - how that could look like a lowercase L to the OP beggars explanation, but I imagine *some* fonts could be graphically crazy enough to afford such confusion.

So I would first try `filename = filename.decode('utf-8')` -- that should allow the `os.path.join` to work.  If `open` then balks at the resulting Unicode string (it might work, depending on the filesystem and OS), next attempt is to try using that Unicode object's `.encode('Latin-1')` and `.encode('utf-8')`.  If none of the encodings work, information on the OS and filesystem in use, which the OP, I believe, hasn't given yet, becomes crucial.

Comment: @Alex, the char is not showing because SO's editor just ignored it after question submitted. I just added the repr(filename) to above code. I'm sure '/dirname' part contains all ASCII chars

Comment: @Alex, thanks for updates, I tried your method but still cannot access the file on disk with the filename it joined.

Comment: @Alex, U+0088 is a C1 control character, it's not uppercase A with anything. Caret??? U+00C2 is LATIN CAPITAL LETTER WITH CIRCUMFLEX ... is that what you meant?

Comment: @John, I finally found the reason, actuall '/dirname' is not a constant but a variable which is unicode type. I get it work by using os.path.join(str(dir_variable), filename.encode('raw_unicode_escape')). Becaus Alex was the first one to answer and due to his detailed explanation, I accept his answer. I also voted up S Mark's answer. Thanks to all.

Comment: @jack: Has `filename` suddenly become a unicode object?? Alex's explanations are always detailed :-) but in this case not relevant to your real problem, which Ignacio was on to right from the beginning but you said that you tried '/dirname' and it didn't work -- this can not have been true (unless you made some other (unpublished) change to your code). In future please show the actual code, actual output, and actual traceback -- don't make it up.

Comment: @John, the 2-byte sequence 0xC2, 0x88, is utf-8 encoding for Unicode codepoint U+00C2, a capital A with a circumflex aka caret over it; not sure what you mean by "C1" since that would be odd and c2 and 88 are both even.

Comment: @Alex: Consider testing your statements in the interactive interpreter before publishing: `'\xc2\x88'.decode('utf8')` produces `u'\x88'` (as you said yourself); `u'\u00c2'.encode('utf8')` produces `'\xc3\x82'`. U+0088 is (as I said) a C1 control character i.e. one of those in the interval U+0080 to U+009F inclusive; C0 control characters are U+0000 to U+001F. Caret != circumflex; consult a reputable dictionary, not urbanfictionary.com :-)

Answer (score 7):

I have fixed the UnicodeDecodeError by adding these lines to `/etc/apache2/envvars` and restarting Apache.

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

as described here: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#if-you-get-a-unicodeencodeerror

I have spent some time debugging this.

Comment: I had the same error while running a django management command and doing these exports in the shell solved it.

Answer (score 2):

```
filename = filename.decode('utf-8').encode("latin-1")
```

works for me with the file from [Splywaj.zip](http://download.appfile.com/Splywaj.zip)

```
>>> os.path.isfile(filename.decode("utf8").encode("latin-1"))
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Evidence problem 1 ###

> It throws out "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)" when executing following code:

```
filename = 'Spywaj.ttf'
print repr(filename)
>> 'Sp\xc2\x88ywaj.ttf'
filepath = os.path.join('/dirname', filename)
```

I can't see how it is possible to get that exception -- both args of os.path.join are str objects. There is no reason to try converting anything to unicode. Are you sure that the above code is exactly what you ran?

#### Evidence problem 2

> Alex's suggestion os.path.join works now but I still cannot access the file on disk with the filename it joined.

```
filename = filename.decode('utf-8')
filepath = os.path.join('/dirname', filename)
print filepath
>> /dirname/u'Sp\xc2\x88ywaj.ttf'
```

Sorry, assuming that `filename` has not changed from the previous snippet, that's definitely impossible. It looks like the result of `os.path.join('/dirname', repr(filename))` ... please ensure that you publish the code that you actually ran, together with actual output (and actual traceback, if any).

#### Confusion

```
new_filepath = filepath.encode('Latin-1').encode('utf-8')
```

Alex meant to try twice, each time with one of those encodings -- not try once with both encodings! As all the characters in filepath were in the ASCII range (see evidence problem 2) the effect was simply filepath.encode('ascii')

#### Simple solution

You know how to find the name of the file that you are interested in:

```
valid_filepath = glob.glob('/dirname/*.ttf')[0]
```

If you must hard-code that name in your script, you can use the repr() function to get the representation that you can type into your script without worrying about utf8, unicode, encode, decode and all that noise:

```
print repr(valid_filepath)
```

Let's suppose that it prints `'/dirname/Sp\xc2\x88ywaj.ttf'` ... then all you need to do is carefully copy that and paste it into your script:

```
file_path = '/dirname/Sp\xc2\x88ywaj.ttf'
```